# c# Using Two MysqlReaders

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

I want to retrive data from two differentables in my mysql data base so i created one connection and two readers, The second reader is not returning any results but the first reader is.

```
 public  List<BlogContentItemClass> BCITLIST = new List<BlogContentItemClass>();

    // GET: api/BlogContents
    [HttpGet]
    public List<BlogContentItemClass> Get(string id)
    {

        string sqlstring = "server=; port= ; user id =;Password=;Database=;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        string Query = "SELECT * FROM test.blogtable where `id` = '" + id + "' ";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader MSQLRD = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        BlogContentItemClass BCIT = new BlogContentItemClass();
        Label BLOGID = new Label();

        if (MSQLRD.HasRows)
        {

            while (MSQLRD.Read())
            {

                string TC = (MSQLRD["Topic"].ToString());
                string CT = (MSQLRD["Category"].ToString());
                string SM = (MSQLRD["Summary"].ToString());
                string BID = (MSQLRD["id"].ToString());

                BCIT.TopicSaved1 = TC;
                BCIT.CategoriesSaved1 = CT;
                BCIT.SummarySaved1 = SM;
                BLOGID.Text = BID;
                BCIT.TotalBodyStackLayout1.Add("Hello");

            }
        }

        BCITLIST.Add(BCIT);
        MSQLRD.Close();

        string Query1 = "SELECT * FROM test.blogbodytable where `BlogID` = '" + BLOGID.Text + "' ";
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(Query1, conn);

        MySqlDataReader MSQLRD1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


        if (MSQLRD1.HasRows)
        {

            while (MSQLRD1.Read())
            {
                string BLOGBODY ;
                BLOGBODY = (MSQLRD1["BlogBody"].ToString());
               BCIT.TotalBodyStackLayout1.Add(BLOGBODY);

            }
        }

        BCITLIST.Add(BCIT);
        conn.Close();
        return BCITLIST;
    }
```

from my code the line `BCIT.TotalBodyStackLayout1.Add("Hello");` in the first reader does add `"hello"` to the `BCIT.TotalBodyStacklayout1`, but the line `BCIT.TotalBodyStackLayout1.Add( BLOGBODY);` does not work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, there are quite a few things I would do different, but the most important one is definitely the fact that your code is an open door for SQL Injection attacks. Use parameterized queries to eliminate that threat.

Comment: You could open multiple database connections with 1 reader per connection

Comment: @Sachith, I did that and it still did not work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled,ok i will correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific what you mean by 'BCIT.TotalBodyStackLayout1.Add(BLOGBODY);' does not work. Are you getting any exception? or if BLOGBODY coming empty? There are few primitive troubleshooting steps you can perform to nail-down the issue

1. confirm what BLOGID.Text you are getting from your previous query and corresponding data is available in  test.blogbodytable for that id.
2. `if (MSQLRD1.HasRows)` is resolving to true
3. Were you able to get inside `while (MSQLRD1.Read())`

Comment: oh yes , i checked the `BLOGID.text` and noticed it didnt have any value,  i replaced it and it was working, but why is the `BLOGID.Text` not available because i set` BLOGID.Text =BID` and `BID = (MSQLRD["id"].ToString());`
`

Comment: So one thing is evident that this is not a issue of "C# using two MySqlReaders". Now coming back to why '(MSQLRD["id"].ToString()' is coming empty, for that you need to do little sanity check like if your first statement is yielding any result at all. Why in your sql statement id is within single quotes like'id'? check if test.blogtable table has corresponding data for the given id and control is going inside 'while (MSQLRD.Read())' in debug mode.